# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" pl/sql error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f2
    (v_nume employee.last_name%TYPE DEFAULT 'Andrew') 
RETURN NUMBER IS 
        salariu employee.salary%type; 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT salary 
        INTO salariu 
        FROM employee 
        WHERE last_name = v_nume; 
        RETURN salariu; 
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'No employees'); 
        WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN 
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Many employees'); 
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'Another error!'); 
END f2;

SELECT f2 FROM DUAL;
```

Hi! What should I do to repair this? Also, can I give to this function a table argument?

Comment: By the way, the `others` exception handler doesn't really make sense. By default, if an exception is not handed, the function will fail with a detailed system error stack showing line numbers etc. It's not helpful to replace all of that useful information with `ORA-20002: Another error!` The other two exception handlers would be better if they included the employee number.

Comment: Side observation:  "WHERE last_name = v_nume; ".  Do you really expect last_name to uniquely identify an employee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the function to the database in order to compile it first, depending on your client program you would probably use a `/` to do so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f2
    (v_nume employee.last_name%TYPE DEFAULT 'Andrew') 
RETURN NUMBER IS 
        salariu employee.salary%type; 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT salary 
        INTO salariu 
        FROM employee 
        WHERE last_name = v_nume; 
        RETURN salariu; 
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'No employees'); 
        WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN 
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Many employees'); 
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'Another error!'); 
END f2;
/
```

Then you can use it:

```
select f2() from dual;
```

Comment: I want to give more VARCHAR parameters to function and return the result in a table. How can I do this?

Comment: You can add extra input arguments like: `f2 (v_nume employee.last_name%TYPE DEFAULT 'Andrew', v_otherarg varchar2)`. How do you really want the result to returned? You obviously can't just select a table from `dual`, you could have the function return a pipelined table (google that), or you could have the function return a record with multiple attributes. Probably best you have a google around and raise another question once you have some idea of how it's going to be used.